# ContourPlot a list of equations generated by the Table command

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation, syntax, assignment

The first command below produces proper contour lines while the second command produces an empty plot. I would think that the two commands should produce the same output. What's going on?

> ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == .04, x^2 + y^2 == .09}, {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}]
>
> ContourPlot[Table[x^2 + y^2 == k, {k, {.04, .09}}], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}]

Comment: try `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[  
    x^2 + y^2 == k, {k, {.04, .09}}], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}]`?

Comment: @kglr, That works. Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `Table` in the first argument with [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html):

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ Table[ x^2 + y^2 == k, {k, {.04, .09}}],
  {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}]
```

[image]